# Object property getting blank in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, javascript-objects

I am trying to implement filter method in Vue component.

I have below filter method:

```
    filterHotels:function(){

            var thisHotels = this.hotelRoomArr;

            console.log(this.hotelRoomArr['107572']['rooms'])

            //this outputs:

            {__ob__: Observer}
            3: (...)
            __ob__: Observer {value: {…}, dep: Dep, vmCount: 0}
            get 3: ƒ reactiveGetter()
            set 3: ƒ reactiveSetter(newVal)
            __proto__: Object


            thisHotels['107572']['rooms'] = {};

            console.log(this.hotelRoomArr['107572']['rooms']);

            //this outputs:

            {__ob__: Observer}
            __ob__: Observer {value: {…}, dep: Dep, vmCount: 0}
            __proto__: Object
    }
```

As seen in above code:

Though I am setting *rooms* property of **thisHotels** to blank object, *rooms* property of **this.hotelRoomArr** also getting changed.

Logically *rooms* property of **this.hotelRoomArr** should not get changed.

What I have to do so that **this.hotelRoomArr** won't get changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its because when you do this `var thisHotels = this.hotelRoomArr;`

`thisHotels` becomes a reference to `this.hotelRoomArr`, when you modify one, it modify the other.

if you want a non-reference copy of the object, you can do this:

`let thisHotels = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.hotelRoomArr))`

I personnally use the JSON object way

Comment: [`Object.assign` does *not* deep-copy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Deep_Clone)

Comment: let thisHotels = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.hotelRoomArr)) .This solves my issue.

Answer (score 2):

When you do `var thisHotels = this.hotelRoomArr;`, `thisHotels` becomes a reference.

Try using the `lodash` function `cloneDeep`:

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#cloneDeep

```js
import cloneDeep from 'lodash/cloneDeep';

...

var thisHotels = cloneDeep(this.hotelRoomArr);
```

This will instead make a copy and prevent `this.hotelRoomArr` from being affected by the changes

Answer (score 0):

When creating the local variable thisHotels, spread hotelRoomArr instead of equating it. That may solve the issue.

```
//top code
var thisHotels = [...this.hotelRoomArr]
//remaining code
```

PS: Better use let instead of var